# Add caching to Zend\Form\Annotation\AnnotationBuilder

Tags: php, caching, annotations, zend-form, zend-framework2

As I've finally found a binary of `memcache` for PHP 5.4.4 on Windows, I'm speeding up the application I'm currently developing.

I've succeeded setting memcache as Doctrine ORM Mapping Cache driver, but I need to fix another leakage: Forms built using annotations.

I'm creating forms according to the Annotations section of the [docs](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.form.quick-start.html). Unfortunately, this takes a lot of time, especially when creating multiple forms for a single page.

Is it possible to add caching to this process? I've browsed through the code but it seems like the `Zend\Form\Annotation\AnnotationBuilder` always creates the form by reflecting the code and parsing the annotations. Thanks in advance.

Comment: may i ask how you got it to work? i never got the both to work together (Doctrine2 and ZendForm2 AnnotationBuilder). Some Example Code would help me. Thank you.

Comment: I'm presuming you haven't found an answer to this - I'm not sure it's possible, at least up through php 5.4 (haven't tried on 5.5, but I don't see any changes that would make it possible).

When I try to save, I'm seeing "can't serialize a closure" errors - I'm presuming the annotation builder is adding closures on to the form it's building, although I don't see any then I do a zend dump() on the resulting form.  

If you find an answer, please do update this!  Thanks!

Comment: @mgkimsal - The real performance changes you'd receive from caching forms (Assuming annotations) exists primarily within the annotation parsing. I put my solution for caching those below. Gave me a noticeable performance boost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might wanna try something like this:

```
class ZendFormCachedController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    protected $_formId = 'form';

    public function indexAction()
    {
            $frontend = array(
                    'lifetime' => 7200,
                    'automatic_serialization' => true);

            $backend = array('cache_dir' => '/tmp/');
            $cache = Zend_Cache::factory('Core', 'File', $frontend, $backend);

            if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
                    $form = $this->getForm(new Zend_Form);
            } else if (! $form = $cache->load($this->_formId)) {
                    $form = $this->getForm(new Zend_Form);
                    $cache->save($form->__toString(), $this->_formId);
            }

            $this->getHelper('layout')->setLayout('zend-form');
            $this->view->form = $form;
    }
```

Found [here](http://blog.fedecarg.com/2008/07/06/zend_form-performance-issues/).

Comment: I'm still hoping that there is a native solution since all results I've found on my fav. search engine belong to ZF1.

Answer (score 1):

Louis's answer didn't work for me so what I did was simply extend AnnotationBuilder's constructor to take a cache object and then modified `getFormSpecification` to use that cache to cache the result. My function is below..

Very quick work around...sure it could be improved. In my case, I was limited to some old hardware and this took the load time on a page from 10+ seconds to about 1 second

```
/**
 * Creates and returns a form specification for use with a factory
 *
 * Parses the object provided, and processes annotations for the class and
 * all properties. Information from annotations is then used to create
 * specifications for a form, its elements, and its input filter.
 *
 * MODIFIED: Now uses local cache to store parsed annotations
 *
 * @param  string|object $entity Either an instance or a valid class name for an entity
 * @throws Exception\InvalidArgumentException if $entity is not an object or class name
 * @return ArrayObject
 */
public function getFormSpecification($entity)
{
    if (!is_object($entity)) {
        if ((is_string($entity) && (!class_exists($entity))) // non-existent class
            || (!is_string($entity)) // not an object or string
        ) {
            throw new Exception\InvalidArgumentException(sprintf(
                '%s expects an object or valid class name; received "%s"',
                __METHOD__,
                var_export($entity, 1)
            ));
        }
    }

    $formSpec = NULL;
    if ($this->cache) { 
        //generate cache key from entity name
        $cacheKey =  (is_string($entity) ? $entity : get_class($entity)) . '_form_cache';

        //get the cached form annotations, try cache first
        $formSpec = $this->cache->getItem($cacheKey);
    }
    if (empty($formSpec)) {
        $this->entity      = $entity;
        $annotationManager = $this->getAnnotationManager();
        $formSpec          = new ArrayObject();
        $filterSpec        = new ArrayObject();

        $reflection  = new ClassReflection($entity);
        $annotations = $reflection->getAnnotations($annotationManager);

        if ($annotations instanceof AnnotationCollection) {
            $this->configureForm($annotations, $reflection, $formSpec, $filterSpec);
        }

        foreach ($reflection->getProperties() as $property) {
            $annotations = $property->getAnnotations($annotationManager);

            if ($annotations instanceof AnnotationCollection) {
                $this->configureElement($annotations, $property, $formSpec, $filterSpec);
            }
        }

        if (!isset($formSpec['input_filter'])) {
            $formSpec['input_filter'] = $filterSpec;
        }

        //save annotations to cache
        if ($this->cache) { 
            $this->cache->addItem($cacheKey, $formSpec);
        }
    }

    return $formSpec;
}
```