# How to use Memcached in Doctrine2 / ZF2?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have set up my code / directories / configuration as outlined in this article: http://www.jasongrimes.org/2012/01/using-doctrine-2-in-zend-framework-2/

So my config file looks something like:

```
<?php
namespace Game;

return array(

    // <snip>

    // Doctrine config
    'doctrine' => array(
        'driver' => array(
            __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver' => array(
                'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
                'cache' => 'array',
                'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/../src/' . __NAMESPACE__ . '/Entity')
            ),
            'orm_default' => array(
                'drivers' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ . '\Entity' => __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver'
                )
            )
        )
    ),
);
```

Now, what do I need to set/change to make Doctrine use Memcached as its caching backend? I have searched a lot on Google, but other than in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12373142/add-caching-to-zend-form-annotation-annotationbuilder), where it says they got it working (but not how), I have not been able to find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had some trouble to get it working and I only have a temporary workaround as I needed to modify the Doctrine ORM Module itself.

First, set the cache to memcache: `'cache' => 'array',` to `'cache' => 'memcache',` in your config above.

Then, define a service factory to create the memcache instance. You can do this in a module class:

**NOTE:** This example bases on *memcache*, not *memcacheD*. But it should be the same for *memcached*.

```
function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'memcache' => function(ServiceManager $sm) {
                $memcache = new \Memcache(); // .. do some configuration and connect
                return $memcache;
            } 
        )
    );
}
```

The last step is to modify the Doctrine ORM Module. Otherwise, it won't create the instance and throws an error.

In `DoctrineModule/Service/CacheFactory.php l61` :

```
$cache->setMemcache($options->getInstance());
```

Becomes:

```
$cache->setMemcache($sl->get($options->getInstance()));
```

(In your case, do this for line 64.) Or find another way to inject a memcached instance into `$options`. Be aware that this should only be a workaround and be fixed as soon as possible. Otherwise, you'll have trouble updating the module.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 8):

They had posted the official way to support it [here](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule/blob/b2c9507603d4f4442fa1f3ead87e14abb80b8073/docs/configuration.md)

Comment: This answer is more up to date and does not require hacking the Doctrine ORM Module. +1

Answer (score 6):

forget the previous answer. after spending hours tracing the errors i found that doctrine looks for "doctrine.cache.instance" the value there should be a string referencing the service you set up in the service manager.

however, due to a bug in the doctrine code base the config is never retrieved. i will submit this to github later.

but the good news is that when no "doctrine.cache.instance" is given the alias "my_memcached_alias" is used.

so the above code can easely be fixed and the awkward hacks removed from the doctrine source.

(**note**: i left the doctrine.cache config in for future compatibility and showing the proper way to set the instance alias)

module.config.php

```
    'doctrine' => array(
            'driver' => array(
                __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver' => array(
                    'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
                    'cache' => 'memcached',
                    'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/../src/' . __NAMESPACE__ . '/Entity'),
                ),
                'orm_default' => array(
                    'drivers' => array(
                        __NAMESPACE__ . '\Entity' => __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            'cache' => array(
                'instance' => 'my_memcached_alias',
            ),
        ),

    'service_manager' => array(
            'factories' => array(
                'my_memcached_alias' => function() {
                    $memcached = new \Memcached();
                    $memcached->addServer('localhost', 11211);
                    return $memcached;
                },
            ),
         ),
```

i hope you have already found a solution by now that doesnt involve a framework modification, but for al the people still searching for answers this will definetly help

Edit:
After Many headaches I found out that th config should be doctrine.cache.memcache.instance

second edit:

here's the correct code

```
'cache' => array(
        'memcache' => array(
            'instance' => 'memcacheService',
        ),
    ),
```

Comment: It looks like that the 'cache' config is no longer needed?

Answer (score 0):

We don't need to change core Doctrine ORM module source.

Change factories to:

```
return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'my_memcache_alias' => function(ServiceManager $sm) {
                $memcache = new \Memcache(); // .. do some configuration and connect
                return $memcache;
            } 
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all install the memcached php extension.

```
~ # > aptitude install php5-memcached
```

After that you will need to configure the memcached servers parameters

```
//app/config/parameters.yml
parameters:
    ...
    memcache_hosts:
        -
            dsn: 127.0.0.1
            port: 11211
```

Next we need to create some services

```
services:
    memcached:
        class: Memcached
        calls:
            - [ addServers, [%memcache_hosts%] ]

    doctrine.cache.memcached:
        class: Doctrine\Common\Cache\MemcachedCache
        calls:
            - [ setMemcached, [ @memcached ] ]
```

After that we will need to add some configuration to config.yml

```
//app/config/config.yml

...
doctrine:
    ...
    orm:
        entity_managers:
            default:
               ...    
               metadata_cache_driver:
                    type: service
                    id: doctrine.cache.memcached
                query_cache_driver:
                    type: service
                    id: doctrine.cache.memcached
                result_cache_driver:
                    type: service
                    id: doctrine.cache.memcached
```

Now We can use Memcached to cache our queries as the Doctrine Doc explains.

Also we have three symfony commands to clear the doctrine cache

```
$> php app/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata 
                 //Clears all metadata cache for an entity manager

$> php app/console doctrine:cache:clear-query 
                 //Clears all query cache for an entity manager

$> doctrine:cache:clear-result 
                 //Clears result cache for an entity manager
```

I have extracted these steps from:

https://blog.42mate.com/implementing-doctrine-caching-with-memcached-in-symfony-2/