# Doctrine2 default result cache

Tags: php, caching, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

Does somebody of you know how to define the default result cache options for doctrine 2 in a zf2 project?

I actually use this code. But is there a way to define it for all repositories and not for each one for them selfe.

```
$em = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
$q = $em->('SELECT i FROM Surgeworks\CoreBundle\Entity\ItemsToCollections i);
$q->useResultCache(true, 3600, 'somecache_id');
$result = $q->getResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

Iam not sure how. I am only familiar with the orm layer and rarely write my own DQL. But I think you should take a look at this post

[How to use Memcached in Doctrine2 / ZF2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463225/how-to-use-memcached-in-doctrine2-zf2)

and these config examples

https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule/blob/b2c9507603d4f4442fa1f3ead87e14abb80b8073/docs/configuration.md